# Why would stat_summary not add up the labels on my barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, geom-bar

I have an aggregated dataset which looks like this one:

```
place<-c('PHF','Mobile clinic','pharmacy','PHF','pharmacy','PHF','normal shop','pharmacy')
District<-c('District1','District1','District1','District2','District2','District3','District3','District3')
cat<-c('public','public','private','public','private','public','private','private')
Freq<-c(7,2,5,4,7,5,1,8)
Q14_HH<-data.frame(place,District,cat,Freq)
```

I create a barplot which looks great:

```
plot<- ggplot(data = Q14_HH, aes(x=place,y=Freq,fill=cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  labs(title="Where do you get your medicines from normally? (human)", 
       subtitle='Precentage of households, n=30',x="", y="Percentage",fill='Outlet type') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1,vjust=0.5))
```

Now I want to put the sum of the frequencies on top of each bar i.e. for each place variable:

```
plot+ stat_summary(geom='text',aes(label = Freq,group=place),fun=sum)
```

But for some reason it won't calculate the sum. I get a warning message:
*Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_text)[image]*

Can someone help me understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are computing the `sum` you have to map the computed `y` value on the `label` aes using `label=..y..` or `label=after_stat(y)`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot <- ggplot(data = Q14_HH, aes(x = place, y = Freq, fill = cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(
    title = "Where do you get your medicines from normally? (human)",
    subtitle = "Precentage of households, n=30", x = "", y = "Percentage", fill = "Outlet type"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))

plot + stat_summary(geom = "text", aes(label = ..y.., group = place), fun = sum)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was experimenting with ..y.. as well but didn't get it quite right. This worked now :)